# Pixahawk compatibility with high voltage digital servos

Tags: flight-controller, digital-servo

I am a novice RC member whom is doing a university project that uses a flight controller to actuate high voltage digital servos. It is part of a ducted fan rocket. The servos : https://hitecrcd.com/products/servos/digital/coreless/hs-7235mh/product ideally would work with 6v-7.4v. They are part of a thrust vectoring mechanism whose actuation is governed by a Pixahawk flight controller: https://www.rcworld.co.za/product_details.php?proid=1507 . We intend on using a 6s Lipo battery to power the components. I would like to confirm if this flight controller is capable of handling up to 7.4V to these servos (the stall current is 1.6A). I had seen in a documentation that the pixahawk can handle up to 10V, as seen in the image below [image] . I would like to confirm if this is true, as I am not 100% if servo power refers to this. Additionally, I had read something about the servo rails being limited to 5V. I have not used a digital servo or flight controller before. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible from the Pixhawk V2 using the Dual Power input.

See the sections "**Power Architecture**" and "**List of features changed on Pixhawk 2 from Pixhawk 1**" from the [documentation](https://hexadrone.fr/img/cms/DRS_Pixhawk-2.pdf).

I recommend you test the Pixhawk without components and measure the outputs to ensure the FMU power supply is separate from the Servo rail.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation! I will look through the specified sections.